# Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt p) = \{a + b\sqrt p\mid a,b \in\mathbb Q\}$ a field only for primes $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt p) = \{a + b\sqrt p\mid a,b \in\mathbb  Q\}$ a field for every prime p?

Will it be a field for any natural number p or for just prime numbers p?

Comment: It's a field for any $p$, but when $p$ is a perfect square, it is just $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: HInt: try to compute reciprocals by rationalizing the denominator.

Comment: Are you familiar with quotient rings and the First Isomorphism Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general result is the following:

> For any $\alpha\in\mathbf Q$, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt \alpha)$ is a field. This field equal to $\mathbf Q$ if $\alpha$ is a square in $\mathbf Q$.
>
> If $\alpha$ is not a square, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt \alpha)$ is a quadratic extension of  $\mathbf Q$, and there exists a *unique* square-free *integer* $d$ such that $\mathbf Q(\sqrt \alpha)=\mathbf Q(\sqrt d) $.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $p$ is a prime $X^2-p$ is irreducible and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt p)=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-p)$. The same argument shows that it is a field if $p$ is not a square.  if $p$ is a square it is also a field since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt p)=\mathbb{Q}$.